# Adding technical decision to JIRA stories

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I want to add decision to JIRA just like I can add comments.
But the decisions have context. This includes options, consequences etc.
Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom issue type](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/add-edit-and-delete-an-issue-type/) for technical decisions.

The custom issue type would have the fields you require (options, consequences, etc.) as [custom fields](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/adding-custom-fields-1047552713.html).

If you make the custom issue of type sub-task then you can add as many technical decisions as you want to a task/story.